# why there isn't any pointer in relational model?

Tags: database, relational-database, relational-model

It is a different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371066/historically-what-made-relational-databases-popular), because as I explain in my own post, my purpose is to find out why databases don't use pointers instead of keys and what are the other options to implement its functionality.

As I read the implementation of relational database, there isn't anything with the concept of `pointer` in it.

Here is my questions:

1. Why there isn't any pointer in the relational model?

Comment: Hi. Please ask one question per question. Also 1 is a faq & 2 is not clear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [historically, what made relational databases popular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371066/historically-what-made-relational-databases-popular)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why there isn't any pointer in the relational model?

Many databases use technical IDs that one could call pointers. It's like generating a number (like an address) with which to find the record in the table.

Say you have a table of orders and another of customers. The customers table would contain some customer ID. A record in the orders table would also contain a customer ID. So an order (a record in the order table) would thus point to the related customer (a record in the customers table).

> Is there any system file feature that isn't implemented by relational model?

I can't think of any. Both systems can be used to store, organize, find, copy, move, backup, and versionize files.

Comment: Do they use keys instead of pointers like described here: 167.99.51.102:8080

Comment: I cannot reach that site. Anyway, yes, the key serves as a unique address in a table.